# How to create database in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, database-connection

Actually I built a GUI to show the result of my program. When I click on the buttons, they need to read the input from a folder, which I choose for them, but I want to have a database to store all the data and load them just one time when I click on the button, not for all the buttons.

I can give an example to show what I want to do: For example I can put a button just for loading the program and reading the input. Then, when I press any button, they don't need to read the data from the folder any more.

I'll appreciate that anyone can help me.

Comment: _Database_ is a very wide term. How about a [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) or a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)?

Comment: Can you share your GUI-code to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a real local database, I'd use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It can be merged with matlab using  [mksqlite](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/1549-matlab-sqlite).

However, as pointed out by @eitan-t, you might not need a real database. It's enough to store your data using some Matlab's own type, like an array of stuct's.